# Can I use iTunes on Ubuntu 9.10 just like how I use it on Windows / Mac?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, itunes

Can I use iTunes on Ubuntu 9.10 in the same way as I do on a Mac or Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run windows programs using [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb) (this link is for installing the recent WINE for Ubuntu releases including 9.10). You can try and follow the instructions [here](http://sudosys.be/?q=itunes_7.3_on_ubuntu_8.04), to install itunes, though this is for ubuntu 8.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not without some form of Windows emulation/virtualisation.

Comment: don't include "this is more appropriate for X" in your question; put it in a comment instead.  thanks